# Run method from loaded class file?

Tags: java

Lets say I am loading classfiles from a folder during runtime:

```
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
```

Lets say I know the method `returnTestString()` exists in the ambiguous class defined above. How can I get that method, without casting the class as the intended class like with `MyClass class = (MyClass) cls.newInstance();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any declared method without casting using reflection. [This post](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/) nicely explains the details.

In short, it's something like this:

```
Class cls = cl.loadClass("com.mycompany.MyClass");
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod ("returnTestString", null);
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
method.invoke(obj, null);
```